# Web RTC , video calling can we record remote RTCMediaStream on ios

Tags: iphone, swift2, openwebrtc

I am working on WebRTC project, and successfully done with RTCVideo calling, now i need to record remote stream on ios device ,my question is is it feasible without MCU?

i already done lots of search over google and stack , thanks in advance

Comment: found any solution for this? or the recording needs to be done at server side?

Comment: yes you can by custom subclass  RTCVideo class and get its buffer than create new video file

Comment: Ankit, and it will have incoming feed and will not have the voice of the person who speaks in our end, right?

Comment: yes its only video you will get from there , for audio  you need to get buffer from your device microphone and speaker both than pass it in video recording

Comment: Did you get anything to record audio from remote stream?